# Virtual function declaration and inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a program that is trying to create derived classes from a basic abstract class. My .h file is here.

```
#ifndef SHIP_H
#define SHIP_H
class Ship
{
  public:
    virtual ~Ship(void) {}
    virtual const char *name(void) const = 0;
    virtual int size(void) const = 0;
    int getX(int i) const;
    int getY(int i) const;
    void print(void) const;
    bool includes(int x, int y);
int level(void) const;
void decreaseLevel(void);
static Ship *makeShip(char ch, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
  protected:
    void setPos(int a1, int b1, int a2, int b2);
    int lev;
  private:
    bool checkConfig(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    int x1,y1,x2,y2;
    };

class AircraftCarrier : public Ship
{
  public:
   AircraftCarrier(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
   virtual const char *name(void) const;
   virtual int size(void) const;
};
```

and in my Ship.cpp file I have:

```
const char *name (void) {

    const char * ret = "AircraftCarrier"; 
    return ret;
}
```

However this isn't declared in the specific scope of my derived class AircraftCarrier. However whenever I add the

```
const char AircraftCarrier :: *name {...}
```

I get an error:

Ship.cpp:46:9: error: cannot convert ‘const char*’ to ‘const char AircraftCarrier::*’ in      return
  return ret;

Comment: please see my answer below. it is completely meet your question

Answer (score 2):

The name of the function you're trying to declare in Ship.cpp is AircraftCarrier::name() and that function should return a const char * based on the declaration in your header file.

```
const char *AircraftCarrier::name() {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

This definition:

```
const char *AircraftCarrier::name() {...}
```

is incorrect. Try use this, and you'll get the "member not found" compile error. Your declaration and definition **must** have an **identical** prototype. So if you're written the:

```
virtual const char *name(void) const;
        ^^^^^                  ^^^^^
```

declaration in .h, then your definition in .cpp must **completely** match the declaration in your proto. The right definition is:

```
const char* AircraftCarrier::name() const 
{
    // your complex code here
}
```

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you!

Comment: 'const' keyword after the arguments list means that the function's body code can't change any instance's member data, unless it was declared with the 'mutable' keyword. This approach is usualy used for getter functions.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
const char* AircraftCarrier :: name {...}
```

The `*` is part of the return type specification, not the functions name.